# How to force methods on objects in Ruby similar to JavaScript using call, apply and bind

Tags: javascript, ruby

In JavaScript you can shoe horn a method onto an object using call, apply or bind methods. I'm curious if there is an equivalent of this kind of thing in Ruby.

```
var item = {
    color:"green"
};


function getColor(){
    return this.color
};


getColor.call(item);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do almost the same in Ruby:

```
item = { 
  color: 'green' 
}

get_color = ->(arg) { 
  arg[:color] 
}

get_color.call(item)  # => "green"
```

`->(foo) { ... }` is a short form for `lambda { |foo| ... }`

Comment: I'm tempted to check this answer but I don't want to go against anything that might be considered Ruby best practices so before I do I guess I should just inquire about that as well.

Comment: I would argue that using lambdas in not aganinst any Ruby best practices. Actually lambdas are used in a lot of different situations: You can pass them to methods like `Array#map`, combine them with `case` blocks or they are used for finder scopes in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use Ruby class system:

```
item = Item.new

item.define_singleton_method(:color) do
  "something"
end

item.color
=> "something"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `bind` an `UnboundMethod` to an object, but *only* if the object is an instance of the `owner` of the `UnboundMethod`:

```
class Super
  def m(arg) "super #@i #{arg}" end
end

class Sub < Super
  def m(arg) "sub #@i #{arg}" end
  def initialize; @i = 'sub' end
end

class Unrelated
  def m(arg) "unrelated #@i #{arg}" end
end

o = Sub.new

um = Super.instance_method(:m)
bm = um.bind(o)
bm.('works')
# => 'super sub works'

um = Unrelated.instance_method(:m)
bm = um.bind(o)
# TypeError: bind argument must be an instance of Unrelated
```